# How to check which link user had used?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Hello I have online course website. I have `authorizecontroller` for admin area and you can access there by typing `www.name.com/area` then you log in and go to the admin area. I also need students to log in here but they should go to different link like `wwww.name.com./LoginStudent`. So the students will come from the page `www.name.com/Course/Detail` and in the detail page button leads him/her to log in controller in admin area. So I want to check if user came from `www.name.com/Course/Detail` I want redirect him/her to `wwww.name.com./LoginStudent` how can I control where did he come from ? 
here is my log in controller ;

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl, LoginModel input)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız.");
            return View(input);
        }


        var yonetici = Db.Members.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Mail == input.EMail && p.Active == true && p.Authority == Authority.Admin);
        if (yonetici == null)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Hatalı E-Posta adresi.");
            ModelState.AddModelError("EMail", " ");
            return View(input);
        }

        if (yonetici.ValidatePassword(input.Sifre) == false)
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Hatalı şifre");
            ModelState.AddModelError("Sifre", " ");
            return View(input);
        }
```

I dont want to send login page by pressing button because I'm using `[Authorize]` so it checks if loged in before or not

well I did this to make it easy but how to make it work on page load

```
 var itemUrl = Request.Url.ToString();
        if (itemUrl.Contains("Participant"))
        {
            ShowErrorMessage("Hatalı Giriş Yaptınız.");
            return View(input);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the previous page (referrer) using `HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();`

Then show appropriate login screen.

Comment: yes I also got that but I need to redirect when the page loads but I couldnt do that I need to run the method to do that

Comment: You can instead customize a single login page and handle the logic to use it in both cases rather than redirecting to different page for specific login.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save this kind of the information somewhere, maybe on a database? If so, you use a column at the database to save the Source Redirect, so You can query and measure on the future. You can pass it before redirect.

Comment: I made something but it checks when button clicks. how could I make it work when pageload in mvc. Editing question